# Triggering downstream build with file parameter without waiting for the job to end

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the [patch parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Patch+Parameter+Plugin) in Jenkins together with the [MultiJob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) to build and test our code.

We have a MultiJob that accepts an SVN patch file as parameter and using the "Current job parameters" checkbox I pass down the patch to downstream job. It usually work.

Now I want to add another regression jobs, but I don't want to add it as a MultiJob phase because I don't want the "master" job to wait for the regression to end.

I tried using the Parameterized Trigger Plugin, but it omits file parameters.
Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want "fire and forget" job - you can use [parameterized-trigger-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-trigger-plugin)
Make sure you are not checking the checkbox [image]
In the Add Parameters, you can choose Predefine Parameters:
[image]